# Episode in tv cartoon series from the 80's featuring mine field of skulls

Tags: story-identification, space, cartoon

There's an episode of a space TV cartoon series that I saw when I was very young – this must have been in the eighties. I remember only one scene, which somehow left a strong imprint in my mind lasting through decades.  I've tried searching but I have very little to go on.  I hope my very short description may ring a bell with somebody.

The scene featured a mine field of sorts, but instead of explosives, it consisted of skull-shaped stationary objects that launched rockets from their mouths.

This particular scene ended with this mine field in the foreground, and the protagonists' space ship(s) retreating in the background.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess two possibilities for this. This sounds like it could be from Ulysses 31. A french/japanese series from around 1981 or 82. Basically a science fiction update of the Odyssey from greek legend. I don't recall the particular scene you mention but it does sound very much in keeping with what I remember of the show. [Here is the Wikipedia page for the show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_31)

Alternatively this could be Battle of the Planets which was an edited dubbed version of japanese anime Gatchaman. Again I don't recall this exact scene but there are 300 plus episods to go through. Again it does sound like what you describe may be from this. Check both these shows out and see if you find anything.